# Hot reloald webpac-dev-server when changing sass

Tags: reactjs, npm, sass, webpack, webpack-dev-server

i have simple webpack build with webpack-dev-server. It's work, and when i changing .js file its autorefreshingin browser. But when i changhing .sass nothing happens. Here is my webpack.confing

```
const { resolve } = require('path');

const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const OpenBrowserPlugin = require('open-browser-webpack-plugin');

const config = {
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',

  entry: [
    'react-hot-loader/patch',
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080',
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    './main.js',
    './assets/sass/main.sass',
  ],

  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/',
  },

  context: resolve(__dirname, 'app'),

  devServer: {
    hot: true,
    contentBase: resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/',
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loaders: [
          'babel-loader',
        ],
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.sass$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: [
            'css-loader',
            {
              loader: 'sass-loader',
              query: {
                sourceMap: false,
              },
            },
          ],
        }),
      },
      { test: /\.(png|jpg)$/, use: 'url-loader?limit=15000' },
      { test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+.\d+.\d+)?$/, use: 'file-loader' },
      { test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, use: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff' },
      { test: /\.[ot]tf(\?v=\d+.\d+.\d+)?$/, use: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream' },
      { test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, use: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml' },
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin({ filename: 'style.css', disable: false, allChunks: true }),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([{ from: 'vendors', to: 'vendors' }]),
    new OpenBrowserPlugin({ url: 'http://localhost:8080' }),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
  ],
};

module.exports = config;
```

Also, please tell me how to make the files get in the right folders during the build (.css to dist/css, js to dist/js), 'cuz rigth now they all go to the root of dest folder.

Answer (score 0):

Hot reloading doesn't work with `extract-text-webpack-plugin`. You should not use it in development and you can easily disable it by setting the `disable` option to true in development. You can use an environment variable like so:

```
new ExtractTextPlugin({
  filename: 'style.css',
  disable: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
  allChunks: true
}),
```

This will only extract the CSS in production mode, so you'd need to run your production build with:

```
NODE_ENV=production webpack [options]
```

Or if you are on windows:

```
set NODE_ENV=production && webpack [options]
```

There is also [cross-env](https://github.com/kentcdodds/cross-env) if you look for a cross platform solution.

---

For getting the JavaScript files to `dist/js` and the CSS file to `dist/css` you could set `output.path` to `dist/js` and then tell `extract-text-webpack-plugin` to generate the file into `../css/style.css`.

```
output: {
  filename: 'bundle.js',
  path: resolve(__dirname, 'dist/js'),
  publicPath: '/',
},
plugins: [
  new ExtractTextPlugin({
    filename: '../css/style.css',
    disable: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
    allChunks: true
  }),
  // other plugins
]
```

Comment: Thanks, you are awesome!

Comment: I realised you're using `copy-webpack-plugin`, so you might want to not change `output.path` but set `ouput.filename` to `js/bundle.js` instead, otherwise the copied files also go in `dist/js`.